# How to get values in a grouped/pivoted datatable in C#

Tags: c#, .net

i have a datatable SrcDt with the below structure

```
SrcDt:

                           0             1
0  Occupational Therapy (66)           
1                  - avg Age  <Sheet1_1_0>
2               - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_2_0>
3      Physiotherapists (72)           
4                  - avg Age  <Sheet1_4_0>
5               - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_5_0>
6        Social workers (89)           
7                  - avg Age  <Sheet1_7_0>
8               - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_7_0>
```

the desire output is as below
i have managed to do it in Python  but want to see if i can do it in C#

```
df.loc[df[1].isna(), 'work_type'] = df[0]
df1 = df.assign(work_type=df['work_type'].ffill()).dropna(subset=[1])

print(df1[['work_type',0,1]])

OutDt:
       work_type             0             1
1  Occupational Therapy (66)     - avg Age  <Sheet1_1_0>
2  Occupational Therapy (66)  - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_2_0>
4      Physiotherapists (72)     - avg Age  <Sheet1_4_0>
5      Physiotherapists (72)  - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_5_0>
7        Social workers (89)     - avg Age  <Sheet1_7_0>
8        Social workers (89)  - Avg.Visits  <Sheet1_7_0>
....
```

Comment: Your structure is not clear. What are your columns? It looks like column 0 contains different columns.

Comment: Column0 row0 contains  "Occupational Therapy (66)" then column 1 is blank, row1 Column0 contains   "- avg Age"  and row1 column1 value is "<Sheet1_1_0>" not sure if that makes sense

Comment: So if you would re-order that table you don't have a chance to find out which sheet belongs to which worktype? You can just use a loop

Comment: not sure if i correctly understand you  on the loop part .however the idea is on the "avg Age" etc i have to look them up on a separate source file  based on work type .what i m trying to achieve is to be able to differentiate  Avg age under each work type

Answer (score 1):

There is no such method and there is no way to simplify this task. What fields belong to which work-type depends on the index of them in the table. Maybe this works for you:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, List<(string, string)>>();
// loop all rows but start with the first that contains a work_type(where the second column is empty/null)
string lastWorkType = null;
foreach (DataRow row in SrcDt.AsEnumerable().SkipWhile(r => !r.IsNull(1)))
{
    if (row.IsNull(1))
    {
        string workType = row.Field<string>(0);
        dict[workType] = new List<(string, string)>();
        lastWorkType = workType;
    }
    else
    {
        dict[lastWorkType].Add((row.Field<string>(0),row.Field<string>(1)));
    }
}

var OutDt = new DataTable();
OutDt.Columns.Add("work_type");
OutDt.Columns.Add();
OutDt.Columns.Add();
foreach(var kv in dict)
{
    foreach(var fields in kv.Value)
    {
        OutDt.Rows.Add(kv.Key, fields.Item1, fields.Item2);
    }
}
```

As bonus you get a dictionary which contains the grouped work-types with their fields.

Comment: this looks almost as i did in Python with 2 line i will try this out and give feedback Thanks